# How to get value of pointer member in struct with boost::interprocess

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, boost-interprocess

I am new to boost library. I am trying to use **boost::interprocess** to allocate a very simple data structure in shared memory. My struct looks like this:

```
struct test {
    int* pInt;
    float* pFloat;
};
```

Here is sender.cpp:

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // delete SHM if exists
    shared_memory_object::remove("my_shm");
    
    // create a new SHM object and allocate space
    managed_shared_memory managed_shm(open_or_create, "my_shm", 1024);

    test* i = managed_shm.construct<test>("my_solve")();
    i->pInt = new int; 
    *(i->pInt) = 2;
    
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the value 2 *(i->pInt)* in receiver.cpp? My receiver.cpp looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    managed_shared_memory managed_shm(open_or_create, "my_shm", 1024);
    test* ans = managed_shm.find<test>("my_solve").first;
    if (ans)
    {
        std::cout << "Read from shared memory\n";
        std::cout << "print address ans: " << ans<< std::endl;
        std::cout << "print address ans->pInt: " << ans->pInt << std::endl;
        std::cout << "print value ans->pInt: " << *(ans->pInt) << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "my_solve not found" << '\n';

    managed_shm.destroy<test>("my_solve");
    // delete SHM if exists
    shared_memory_object::remove("my_shm");

    return 0;
}
```

And I get error:

> read access violation with `*(ans->pInt)`

Thanks in advance!

----------UPDATED----------

I fixed in **sender.cpp** by allocating like this:

```
    allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>int_alloc(managed_shm.get_segment_manager());
    test* i = managed_shm.construct<test>("my_solve")();
    auto allocated_ints = int_alloc.allocate(1); 
    i->pInt = allocated_ints.get();
```

But I still have the same error. Do I need to change anything in **receiver.cpp**?

Comment: You can't, the `test` object itself is in shared memory, but the `int` you allocate with `new` is your process memory, reading it from another process directly will upset the OS. Can't you just have the `int` and `float` values directly?

Comment: @Kaldrr Oh I see. This is just my test for another project, I need to create pointer in struct. So do you know how to create it in shared memory?

Answer (score 0):

Since you allocated `pInt` with `new int` in the **receiver** process, it will contain an address that is only valid there. You're trying to access that address in the **sender** process, where it is unmapped at best or pointing to a completely different data structure at worst.

Luckily, the boost::interprocess module provides [allocators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.allocator_introduction.allocator) that allocate memory inside the shared memory segment for you:

```
allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
  allocator_instance(managed_shm.get_segment_manager());
auto allocated_ints = allocator_instance.allocate(100);
i->pInt = allocated_ints.get();
```

Note that allocators are restricted to a single type, so you will need a second allocator for your `float*`.
See also the ["quick guide for the impatient"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container) for a copy-pastable example of allocating a `std::vector<int>` inside the shared memory.

Comment: I tried your example code for allocating `pInt` and I have error:  `Error C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<U,DifferenceType,OffsetType,0>' to 'int *'`. Anything wrong?

Comment: Apparently you need to call `.get()` on the returned object to get a raw pointer. see edit.

Comment: Do I need to change anything in **receiver.cpp**? I still get the same error of reading access :((